# Programatically created RadioGroup OnClicked reading standard Android

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-button, android-radiogroup

---

Hi people below is my code what exactly I am doing is that I am trying to create radio group programmatically, which is done and my code is working fine for creating even for reading, but more I am concern about the standard how exactly we use to read on click of group, I feel at some point my code is taking too much of memory, I want to know that is there any other efficient good way to do this.

---

```
private void checkOnClickedRadioGroupCalled(ArrayList<LinearLayout> setRadioGroupValuesLinearLayoutList) {
        for (final LinearLayout group : setRadioGroupValuesLinearLayoutList) {
            String tag = group.getTag() + "_RadioGroup";
            System.out.println("Radio group tag name : - " + tag);
            final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewWithTag(tag);
            if(radioGroup!=null) {
                radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    RadioButton mButton1 = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(0);
                    RadioButton mButton2 = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(1);
                    //add this in constant
                    String idYes = group.getTag()+"Yes";
                    String idNo = group.getTag()+"No";
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                        System.out.println(" hascode of id getting as "+idYes.hashCode()+" And No " +idNo.hashCode());
                        if(mButton1.isChecked() && mButton1.getId() ==idYes.hashCode()) {
                            System.out.println(mButton1.getText() + "  :- Text of radio button");
                        } if(mButton2.isChecked()&& mButton2.getId()==idNo.hashCode()) {
                            System.out.println(mButton2.getText() + "  :- Text of radio button");

                        }
                    }



                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do u mean by "code is taking too much of memory" ?

Comment: if you want yes/no behavior simply use `android.widget.Switch` or `android.widget.ToggleButton`

Comment: i am checking every radio group on page , when radio button is clicked.suppose there are n number of  radio group.

Comment: thanks pskink , but on some part i have multiple buttons not only on and off

Comment: so what do you have problems with? you have `int checkedId` and what else do you need?

Comment: i dont what  for (final LinearLayout group : setRadioGroupValuesLinearLayoutList) {} this line is there any thing instead of this where i directly can check which radiogroup id is clicked?

Comment: Here I am facing one more issue, while coming back again, when I am clicking again on no/yes/unchecked button at that movement I just tried to call radio.clearChecked(); but I faced looping problem on that movement. And app crash. I tried to called radio. ClearCheckd() in different way but it won't worked for me. Any help?